# Allow user to submit data 3 times in a day with Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

On my Codeigniter project, I would like to allow user to submit data into database only 3 times in a day (that user can submit on another day). Have anyone know the better way to do this?

Sorry for my bad English and duplicated question.

Comment: Please could you tell what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

field

[create_perday], [timestamp_update], [reset_times]

create_perday - times of update [ex. value = 1, 2, 3]

reset_times - is boolean [0 = not reset, 1 = reset]

***sudo code :***

```
if(date(timestamp_update) > date(now) ) { // check date
     if(!reset_times) {
          doReset[times]
     }

     if(create_perday < 3) { // check times
          create_perday = create_perday + 1;
          return true;
     } else { 
          return false;;
     }
}
```